# How to indent or unindent lines in a block of text?

Tags: indentation, visual-block

I use two spaces in my indentation of codes. What are the possible ways to indent or unindent a block of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I use two spaces in my indentation of codes.

First off, you should set the [`'shiftwidth'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27shiftwidth%27) option to 2, to match the number of spaces you want to use as indentation. You will probably also want to set [`'expandtab'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27expandtab%27) so that Vim will keep using spaces for indentation once you get to 8 spaces (or whatever the tab size is set to.) So:

```
:set shiftwidth=2 expandtab
```

> What are the possible ways to indent or unindent a block of code?

If you have the block visually selected, then you can use the [`>`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#v_%3E) command to indent it and the [`<`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#v_%3C) command to unindent it. You can pass these commands a "count" to indent/unindent the visual block by multiple `shiftwidth`s.

In normal mode, you can use the [`>`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3E) or [`<`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3C) command followed by a motion to indent/unindent the lines covered by that motion.

You also have the [`>>`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3E%3E) or [`<<`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3C%3C) commands to indent/unindent "count" lines (or a single line, without a count.)

These are a few of the ways in which you can indent/unindent an existing block. There are others available while you're in insert mode, either automatically (e.g. [`'autoindent'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27autoindent%27) or using indent expressions) or manually ([`Ctrl-T`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-T) to indent, [`Ctrl-D`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-D) to unindent, the TAB key can be set to indent by setting an option such as [`'softtabstop'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27softtabstop%27) to match `'shiftwidth'`, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

You can combine the `>` and `<` operators with `%` to indent blocks of code.

The `%` key will jump to the matching parenthesis, bracket or brace if your cursor is sitting on one of these characters: `(`, `)`, `[`, `]`, `{` or `}`.

For an example, say you have a block of code like this and you want to indent it:

```
{
  stuff here
}
```

To indent the code block, put the cursor on one of the braces (either one will work), type `>` followed by `%`.

Answer (score 1):

`:help left`

In `ex mode` you can use `:left` or `:le` to align lines a specified amount. 
Specifically, `:left` will *Left align lines in the [range]. It sets the indent in the lines to [indent] (default 0).*

`:%le3` or `:%le 3`  or `:%left3` or `:%left 3` will align the entire file by padding with three spaces.

`:5 le 4` will pad line 5 with 4 spaces

`:5,7 le 3` will align lines 5 through 7 by padding them with 3 spaces.

`:le` without any value or `:le 0` will left align with a padding of 0.

This works in `vim` and `gvim`.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235839/indent-multiple-lines-quickly-in-vi/32509423#32509423